# Deserialize Json to DataSet

Tags: c#, json, wcf, xamarin, json.net

We have a WCF webservice that returns a DataSet serialized into JSON, when using our WPF application we are able to deserialize the JSON back into a DataSet without problem however when deserializing on our Xamarin.IOS app we end up with an empty Dataset. We are using JSON.NET to serialize and deserialize our JSON.

After some more research I have discovered that when serializing a DataSet in a Xamarin app I end up with a large amount of localization information which doesn't happen when serializing the JSON on our webservice. I'm assuming that it is not deserializing properly because this information is missing.

This is using the example from the JSON.NET documentation which exhibits the same behaviour as our app.

```
        string json = @"{
                          'Table1': [
                            {
                              'id': 0,
                              'item': 'item 0'
                            },
                            {
                              'id': 1,
                              'item': 'item 1'
                            }
                          ]
                        }";

        DataSet ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row["id"] + " - " + row["item"]);
            }                
        }
```

The above code works as expected when run in a Windoews app i.e. a console or WPF app, but in a Xamarin app it returns a empty DataSet.

Thanks

Comment: Hii, look at this link if you get help... http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: Use JSON.NET ..It may be Helpfull

Comment: Post your json string. And post your stuff / code what you are tried.

Comment: @Alok sorry I should have made it more clear we are using JSON.NET